# 502 bad gateway error on elastic beanstalk

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, plotly-dash

I am trying to deploy a dash app ( which is based on flask ) on elastic beanstalk. The code was deployed successfully but it is showing 502 bad gateway error.

[This is the image I am getting upon deploying the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cjwm.png)

[This is the error I get when I click the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BOlM.png)

What is the solution to this error ?

Comment: check the app's logs first. "eb logs" command

Comment: I added an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63111282/how-can-i-fix-502-error-in-a-flask-application-that-i-uploaded-in-aws/63351418#63351418

Answer (score 1):

First of I would check 2 things:

- That the server is really running, thats mostly the cause of 502
- I would check that load balancer (and its security group) uses to the same port where the server is running https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.elb.html

But there are many other problems that may cause 502 (copied from Google):

Network errors - DNS issues, routing problems, and ISP related issues can also lead to a 502 Bad Gateway error. Server software timeouts - This error can also occur when a web server takes more time to complete and a caching tool reaches its timeout values that time. Slow queries can also cause this problem too.

Answer (score 0):

was facing same issue .just Realized that nginx is connecting to node on 8081. Changed node port to 8081 and all is good now..